# mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22) and 'nothingHappensError'

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying execute mysql scripts in python and have some problems

setup:

```
import mysql.connector as connection


conn = connection.connect(host="localhost", database='db_filmbot',
                          user="root", passwd="root", use_pure=True)
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

Problem 1: mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'blankval' in 'field list'

[Data example for problem 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TpOs.png)

```
values = (user.id, user.first_name.replace('ᅠ', 'blankval'), user.username, 
          user.last_name.replace('ᅠ', 'blankval'), photo)

# (498365244, 'blankval', 'nowayq', 'blankval', 'AgACAgIAAxUAAWPDASHSIGNju11djyN9kc5ngFsLgx2t4nTAAL2pzEbPHO0HUhrTLjwgPztAQADAgADYwADLgQNEXTAQAD9qcxGzxztB0BNEXT640NEXT640NEXT89172')

query = """
            INSERT INTO db_filmbot.user
            (tg_id, tg_firstname, tg_username, tg_lastname, tg_profile_photo)
            VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s);
        """ % values
cursor.execute(query)
```

Problem 2: nothing happens when the code is executed

[Data example for problem 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1X1z.png)

```
values = (user.id, film_id)
# (498365244, 1)
query = """
            SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
            INSERT INTO db_filmbot.user_has_films
            (user_tg_id, films_film_id)
            VALUES(%s, %s);
        """ % values
cursor.execute(query, multi=True)
```

I tried change values, rename columns, add different quotes, swap '% value' with text formatting as f'sql script {value}', give execute function 2 params query and value with '?' and '%s' in value fields but nothing helps

Answer (score 0):

```
        values = (user.id, user.first_name.replace('ᅠ', 'blankval'), user.username,
              user.last_name.replace('ᅠ', 'blankval'), photo)
    query = """
                REPLACE INTO db_filmbot.user
                VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s);
            """
    cursor.execute(query, values)
    values = (user.id, film_id)
    cursor.execute('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;')
    query = """
                INSERT INTO db_filmbot.user_has_films
                VALUES(%s, %s);
            """
    cursor.execute(query, values)
    conn.commit()
```